# Magneto 2 Payment module - cannot get credit card number

Tags: magento-2.3

I have the following code but cannot get the credit card information to come through. I echo it and it just shows blank. Not sure why.  Any help is appreciated

```
    namespace Cytruslogic\Subscriptions\Model;
    use \Stripe\Stripe;
    /**
     * Pay In Store payment method model
     */
    class StripeSubscriptions extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
    {

        /**
         * Payment code
         *
         * @var string
         */

        CONST CODE          = 'stripesubscriptions';
        protected $_code    = self::CODE; 

        /**
         * Availability option
         *
         * @var bool
         */
        protected $_isOffline                   = false;

        protected $_isGateway                   = true;
        protected $_canCapture                  = true;
        protected $_canAuthorize                = true;




        public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $Payment, $Amount) 
        {

            echo $Payment->getCcType();
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Testing'));

           // echo $payment->getCcNumber();

              /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $billing */
              /*
              $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();

              try {
                  $requestData = [
                      'amount'        => $amount * 100,
                      'currency'      => strtolower($order->getBaseCurrencyCode()),
                      'description'   => sprintf('#%s, %s', $order->getIncrementId(), $order->getCustomerEmail()),
                      'card'          => [
                          'number'            => $payment->getCcNumber(),
                          'exp_month'         => sprintf('%02d',$payment->getCcExpMonth()),
                          'exp_year'          => $payment->getCcExpYear(),
                          'cvc'               => $payment->getCcCid(),
                          'name'              => $billing->getName(),
                          'address_line1'     => $billing->getStreetLine(1),
                          'address_line2'     => $billing->getStreetLine(2),
                          'address_city'      => $billing->getCity(),
                          'address_zip'       => $billing->getPostcode(),
                          'address_state'     => $billing->getRegion(),
                          'address_country'   => $billing->getCountryId(),
                          // To get full localized country name, use this instead:
                          // 'address_country'   => $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($billing->getCountryId())->getName(),
                      ]
                  ];

                  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create($requestData);
                  $payment
                      ->setTransactionId($charge->id)
                      ->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                  $this->debugData(['request' => $requestData, 'exception' => $e->getMessage()]);
                  $this->_logger->error(__('Payment capturing error.'));
                  throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment capturing error.'));
                }
                */
                return $this;
        }

        public function authorize(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $Payment, $Amount) 
        {
            echo 'authorize';

             $Order = $Payment->getOrder();

             print_r($Payment->getCcNumber());
        }

        public function getConfigPaymentAction()
        {
            return self::ACTION_AUTHORIZE_CAPTURE;
        }

        /**
         * Test method to handle an API call for authorization request.
         *
         * @param $request
         * @return array
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         */
        public function makeAuthRequest($request)
        {
            $response = ['transactionId' => 123]; //todo implement API call for auth request.

            if(!$response) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Failed auth request.'));
            }

            return $response;
        }

        /**
         * Test method to handle an API call for capture request.
         *
         * @param $request
         * @return array
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         */
        public function makeCaptureRequest($request)
        {
            $response = ['success']; //todo implement API call for capture request.

            if(!$response) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Failed capture request.'));
            }

            return $response;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Help us help you, by providing a detailed explanation of what is going on. What are you echo'ing? What value do you expect to see? Where do you expect to see these values from? How can you test that this is or is not working? "I echo it and it just shows blank. Not sure why." Isn't much help for the community to help you. Expand on your answer and I'm sure you'll have better luck receiving some help.

Comment: Thee values come from the payment form in the magento checkout.  I expect $Payment->getCcType() to return a valid credit card type.  I see this in the console in the frontend when I click on place order.